# How to close modal pop up dialog box opened on click of a custom button in salesforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, modal-dialog

Need to close the Modal dialog box on click of cancel button like the way it happens if we click on the "cross" on the upper right corner of the pop up.

Tried `window.close()` but it works only when we have used `window.open()` to open the pop up.

Here we have used the following code to get this pop up

```
function openDialog(visualforcePage){

    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/' + visualforcePage +'")}'; 
    var child_domain = iframe_url.substring(0, iframe_url.indexOf('/', 9)); 
    var parent_domain = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host; 
    var j$modalDialog = j$('<div></div>') 

    .html('<iframe id="iframeContentId" src="' + iframe_url + '&parent_domain=' + parent_domain + '" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" />') 

    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false, 
        title: 'Submit Quote Document', 
        resizable: false, 
        width: 900, 
        height: 700, 
        autoResize: true, 
        modal: true, 
        draggable: false, 
        overflow: scroll         
    }); 
    j$modalDialog.dialog('open'); 

}
openDialog("SubmitQuoteDocument?Id="+opportunityId);
```

[image: Modal Dialog]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please edit your question with better format. Thank you

Comment: @Robert Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ussing Jquery and Bootstrap modal just use `$("#modalId").modal("hide");`